# xml and fragments basics

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am brand new to fragments and am having a bit of trouble with getting them to work properly. With the code I have now, my ListView overlaps my toolbar. When I move the toolbar out of the framelayout to avoid this, the listview stops showing up. My XML:

Here's my `MainActivity`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.oenders1.oenders1project3.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/tbrMain"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the `MainFragment`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.oenders1.oenders1project3.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtEmpty"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lstToDo"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the java:

```
MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();

mainFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, mainFragment)
            .commit();
```

Sorry if this has been asked. I came up short in my search for a similar question. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You are missing a closing `</LinearLayout>` tag in your main fragment XML.  Don't know if this be because you forgot to copy it over to SO, or really missing.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, just missed it in copy.

Comment: In your `MainActivity` xml file change  android:orientation="horizontal" to  android:orientation="vertical" of `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate method in MainActivity , add this

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tbrMain);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Your MainActivity should be similar to this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tbrMain);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();

        mainFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, mainFragment)
            .commit();
    }
}
```

If this was already added, post you MainActivity class

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it working! I think I just had my linearlayout in the wrong orientation!